# Warrior with two long swords. Penalties?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Suppose I have a warrior who wants to wield two long swords, one in each hand (clearly). What are the penalties associated to this combat style, and which abilities can I choose in order to reduce the penalties to a minimum?

Answer (score 18):

In D&D 3.5, if you have the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, your penalties for two longswords are -4/-4. You can reduce this penalty to -2/-2 by wielding a light off-hand weapon.

The feat Oversized Two-Weapon Fighting (Complete Adventurer page 111) allows you to treat a longsword as a light weapon, which would reduce your penalty to -2/-2.

It's possible to reduce the penalties even further by taking the Tempest prestige class (Complete Adventurer p81). At level 2 the penalties reduce from -2/-2 to -1/-1, and at level 4 to -0/-0. You can meet the prerequisites for this prestige class at fighter level 6 and attack with two longswords at -0/-0 by total level 10.

Comment: That was the feat I was thinking of!

Comment: IIRC you need Ambidexterity as well to get down to -4/-4... EDIT: strike that, Ambidexterity appears to have gone the way of THACO...

Comment: You could also add in "Weapon Focus (Long Sword)" for a further +1 attack bonus to both hands.

Comment: @alesplin Ambidexterity was a 3rd edition feat that got subsumed into the 2W-Fighting feat in 3.5e.

Answer (score 4):

You would take a -6 attack penalty for your "main hand weapon" and a -10 penalty for your "off hand weapon".  If instead you weilded a longsword and a shortsword you would take -4, and -8 respectively.  The primary way to lessen this is by taking the [Two Weapon Fighting feat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#twoWeaponFighting).  It lessens the main hand penalty by 2, and the off hand penalty by 6.

From the [D20 SRD (Hypertext SRD)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm)

Comment: the feat would produce a -4/-4. However, I used to have -2/-2, although I don't understand why. My question stems from this.

Comment: @Stefano Borini Were you playing a goliath, as they can use normal weapons as one handed weapons?  I believe there is also a feat you can take to allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.0, You could take 2-weapon fighting, ambidexterity, light off-hand weapon.  The penalty would be -2/-2.  With 2 long swords, it would be -4/-4.

In  3.5 (on page 160)
One could take 2 weapon fighting and take a light offhand weapon would have a penalty of -2/-2.  If your fighter takes 2 long swords (medium offhand weapon), the penalty would be -4/-4.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from PHB:

main_hand - off_hand (attack bonus penalties).

Normal penalties –6  –10
Off-hand weapon is light  –4  –8
Two-Weapon Fighting feat  –4  –4
Off-hand weapon is light and  –2  –2

Also keep in mind that no matter what, an off-hand weapon's damage rolls receive only *half* (rounded down) your strength modifier.