# Is there a way to completely eliminate the penalties for Two-Weapon Fighting?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

From what I can tell, using Two-Weapon Fighting and having a Light weapon in your offhand at best reduces the penalty to -2/-2.  Is there an official 3.5 method of completely eliminating this penalty?  I do intend to eventually progress into further TWF with Improved TWF as well, but planning out my feats and the like I'd like to find a way to get rid of that last -2/-2 penalty if I can.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, if you can get yourself a second head (since multiheaded is an inherited template with at least +2LA it's probably quite difficult to get until later on where adjusting your character's race/templates becomes cheap and easy). 
Also, this is obviously not something you "progress into" at all, you either have it (and make all TWF feats obsolete) or you're stuck with the last -2/-2, so if the chance of your DM allowing the growing of a second head mid-campaign (or you starting with a +2LA template) are slim, you should go with normal TWF feats anyway.

Savage Species page 125:

> Superior Two-Weapon Fighting or Superior Multiweapon Fighting (Ex):
>   Because each head controls one arm (or analogous weapon-using limb), a
>   multiheaded creature has no penalty on attack rolls for attacking with
>   multiple weapons, and the number of attacks and the damage bonus for
>   each weapon are calculated as though the weapon were held in a primary
>   hand.

It basically allows you to wield two weapons of your choice (even two non-light weapons) and get each of those weapons' full attacks at no penalty whatsoever.

Comment: +1 just because this suggestion made me laugh. It's not often that you see a question for which "grow yourself a second head" is a valid answer. :)

Comment: What are some ways to gain two heads without a template?  I'm sure there are a few two-headed races but I can't think of any off the top of my head.

Comment: Y'know, if you *can* get that second head thing going, you can take the deeply obscure feat [Multiple Head Casting](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fc/20010223a). Just putting that out there.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Let's not forget Zaphod Beeblebrox (in some versions) growing a second head to split his brain in two :)

Comment: The explanation doesn't make much sense, though.  If you have each head independently controlling one hand, sure, you'd lose the concentration penalty, but realistically (insofar as that word applies to such a scenario!) wouldn't this be offset by new difficulty in *coordinating* the two sides so they don't get in each other's way?

Comment: @MasonWheeler You'd have to avoid horizontal swings and the head who isn't controlling the lower body needs to react to stepping&leaning and use those properly for attacks (which requires some practice), resulting in a fighting style like that of a normal TWF guy (who has the same worries of getting in his own way, but can't concentrate on both arms as well) but better. We also have to consider that this scenario does not explicitly cause the two heads to have different personalities (might be one consciousness using two brains, using the extra brainpower for micromanagement instead of +INT).

Answer (score 16):

There is the **Tempest** prestige class in *Complete Adventurer* (pp. 81-82).

It reduces the penalty to 0 at Tempest lvl 4 (with light offhand weapon), but restricts you to light armor. This is also somewhat offset by a +3 unnamed bonus to AC (at Tempest level 5).

You also get benefits of some weapon-dependant feats (like Weapon Focus) to both weapons (you get Weapon Focus for a scimitar and also apply it to the dagger you hold offhand).

To become a Tempest you need BAB +6 and several feats, all Spring Attack and TWF related.

Comment: Whether getting stuck with six levels of tempest is better than a -2/-2, on the other hand, is not a thing we're considering ;)

Comment: Tempest has 5 levels only.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The Tempest prestige class (Complete Adventurer page 81), available to sixth-level fighters, gains the Ambidexterity ability.

> Ambidexterity (Ex): For a tempest of 2nd lvl or higher, her attack
>   penalties for fighting with two weapons are lessened by 1 (from -4 to
>   -3, or from -2 to -1 if the off-hand weapon is a light weapon). At 4th lvl, the attack penalties are lessened by another 1 (from -3 to -2, or
>   to +0 if the off-hand weapon is a light weapon). The character loses
>   this ability when fighting in medium or heavy armor.

(Read about in [Jonathan Drain's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/2799/11895) to a related question.)

Comment: Umm.... I do remember that PrC but... dandwiki?  Bad source to be linking to, as anything that isn't SRD gets thrown into "homebrew" and is technically illegal to be put up there anyways.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to Pathfinder's open SRD. Looking further at D&D Wiki I had the same thoughts. I'll replace it with the CA page number.

Comment: There is an SRD, but that's d20srd.com and pretty much only has content from the core books and some alternate rules and such from UA for the most part.  Content from most of the other books is considered "intellectual property" and never made it to the SRD.

Comment: @Dorian *Homebrew* isn't illegal—I mean, it might be at your table, but not in a cops-and-courts sort of way.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: He worded that poorly: danddwiki is a bad source, as everything there that isn't SRD is either homebrew or is illegal in a cops-and-courts sort of way.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I assume Dorian was referring to the fact that transcribing material not published under the OGL (or the GNU FDL) into the wiki may count as a copyright violation, if not done with the original publisher's permission (which I assume, in this case, they don't have). The Tempest page, in particular, seems to be a blatant copy-paste from Complete Adventurer.

Comment: @HeyICanChan What they said.

Answer (score 2):

Two levels of the Bloodclaw Master prestige class from the Tome of Battle gives superior two weapon fighting, negating the penalty, but it only works with daggers or tiger claw weapons.
You also need 9 ranks of jump to get in, and three tiger claw manoeuvres.

Given how synergistic those manoeuvres are with TWF, I'd recommend doing it anyway, and a single level dip into Warblade, from the same book (and recommended by me to anyone who uses a weapon heavier than a dagger) will give you all three, along with a d12 and full BAB.

Alternatively, if you're more of a rogue build, Swordsage gives a lighter combat chassis, but with a few more manoeuvres known, and the shadow hand manoeuvres in particular complement a rogue nicely.